# serializers.MultipleChoiceField causing error

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use a multiple choice field in my profile serializer to represent a many to many relationship between a profile instances and language instances. I'm getting the following error when doing a GET request through a ModelViewSet: `ManyRelatedManager object is not iterable`

## Serializer

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
...
languages = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGES)

class Meta:
    model = Profile

    fields = [
        ...
        "languages"
    ]
```

## Language model

```
class Language(models.Model):
    profile = models.ManyToManyField(
        Profile,
        related_name="languages",
        blank=True
    )
    ...
```

Comment: How is the `LANGUAGES` variable defined?